# how to combine ls command with bash script on a mac

Tags: macos, bash, automation

I need to know how to do a few things:
1. how to execute the ls command with a variable and filter the result with grep, and then put the result into another variable

I search for tutorials, but couldn't find a similar example, plus I tried to play with the syntax, but could make it work.
So here is the script in a syntax which I know is wrong, but I wrote it just to more clear on what I need.

And I would be happy if someone could tell my how to properly concatenate in bash.

Thanks ahead :)

```
#!/bin/bash
executable=$1;
outputs_inputs=$2;
inputs=ls $outputs_inputs | grep "in";
outpus=ls $outputs_inputs | grep "out";

for i in $inputs; do
 myoutput=$executable < i;
 for j in $outputs; do
  if(opendiff $myoutput j){
   echo j is equal to i's output
  }
 done;
done;
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: As always, if you don't know the syntax, go read a tutorial or the reference manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html I'm not sure why newbies in shells don't treat them as serious programming languages with and feel like they can feed whatever imagined syntax into it and it will just work.

Comment: I think you need to use backticks! Put them around the command you would  send to the terminal

Comment: thanks for the shellcheck, I didn't know this existed.

Comment: and by the way I searched for tutorials and example, but I couldn't find any that combined ls with a variable, I didn't just feed it with my own syntax and thought it would work....

Comment: @PeterCogan Not backticks; that syntax has been obsoleted by `$(...)` for a very long time.

Comment: ok lol - I guess I'm stuck in the stone age :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problems start with the fact that you are trying to assign output of commands to a variable. For that you need [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution), as advised by Peter and chepner - backticks ``` `` ``` or the preferred newer form `$(...)`, otherwise you are just assigning strings. And even as strings, because of the whitespace and lack of quoting you are assigning it wrong.

```
inputs=ls $outputs_inputs | grep "in";
```

^-----------^ ^--------------------------------------^ those are two separate things

To sum up you need to change

```
inputs=ls $outputs_inputs | grep "in";
outpus=ls $outputs_inputs | grep "out";
```

to something like this

```
inputs=$(ls $outputs_inputs | grep "in";)
outpus=$(ls $outputs_inputs | grep "out";)
```

Why you are using **ls** in the first place is beyond me and the scope of this reply. Also check the [if-then-else](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) syntax as yours is something else.